# How to get socket ID/handle/descriptor for an already open connection? (.NET,C++,Delphi)

Tags: c#, .net, c++, delphi, sockets

my question is stated in the title. How exactly do I do that?

I have an open connection and I want to "hijack" it and send my custom messages through it. From my understanding that is done with sockets and their handlers.

Any language would do but C#.NET is preferred.

Thank you

**UPDATE:** What exactly am I trying to achieve: I want to implement a keep-alive system for postgresql clients. That means get all the connections open to a postgresql database and every 5 minutes querying the database "select version()" to keep the connection alive. That's about it. It's for educational purposes mostly.

But I want to use this for any kind of connection.

Anyone? Ideas? Nothing? :(

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done that easily (or *at all*). Could you please give us more information about what you're trying to achieve ? Maybe another solution exists.

Comment: Any ideas? It's a bit puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

This library: [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/) promises doing *capturing, injecting, analyzing and building packets using any .NET language such as C# and VB.NET* ([more info](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx))

It is the library used by [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and it is for sure that it can capture and analyze.