# C# Finding a socket ID?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcp

Recently I have started working on a program that will monitor the packets of one of my open-source programs in an attempt to learn more about programming and networking. Also, I want to add additional functionality to the program without editing the source, like an external control panel.

(I used WPE Pro to filter packets in case you'r wondering, WireShark is too much hassle for such a simple task.) One thing bothers me though, the Socket ID.

I know what it is, and I've asked a question about it before, but I cant figure out how to use it/assign one/intercept one.

Without the right socket ID, my program wont be able to do anything, so my question is if it's possible to find out what Socket ID a socket is using, once you capture the packet?

If not, are there any other ways of doing? -or possible other languages like Visual Basic?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742763/how-to-get-socket-id-handle-descriptor-for-an-already-open-connection-net-c

Comment: The answer there is wrong, SharpPcap cant get the Socket ID. If I'm wrong, please correct me in the form of an answer, since that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, by socket ID, you mean the return value of a successful call to `socket()` function, I don't think there's a way.

The closest thing you can obtain is the process ID because, as you may already know, each IP packet has a destination that's described by the tuple (IP address, port) and inside a system only one socket can be successfully bound to that tuple. Utilities like TCPView are able to map an IP tuple to a process, so a way does exist *if that information is enough for you*.

If that's not the case, I'm not aware of any method to retrieve the socket ID you need *if* the target application is not collaborative.

Comment: First, thank you for your reply. When using WPE Pro to filter packets, each packet has the same 'socket id' to uniquely identify a connection. So if I understand correctly, there is a chance this socket id is equal to the program's process ID, even though it can change over time? I wish the source code of the program would help me out, but I cant find anything remotely related to creating the socket connection.

Comment: Well, I took a look to WPE Pro and it seems it (also) uses DLL injection. It doesn't get the socket ID from the packet. That's a whole different story...

Comment: I see.. I did find an interesting function though: WSADuplicateSocket(), but I cant find a decent example anywhere.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, using `WSADuplicateSocket()` requires the target application to be collaborative. I don't know if this is your case or if target applications are unaware of your program. In fact, it requires an IPC channel between your program and the target application and the latter obviously needs to handle that IPC.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, the only way of getting the server to be collaborative is to get the right socket ID. But I think your first comment hit the spot, I'm supposed to hook my program to a DDL. I guess this answers my question, I'll mark it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This library: [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/) promises doing capturing, injecting, analyzing and building packets using any .NET language such as C# and VB.NET ([more info](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx)).

It is the library used by [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and it is for sure that it can capture and analyze.

Comment: Yep, that's what Cristian said. I apreciate your help, but SharpPcap doesn't have such an option unfortunatly.

Answer (score 0):

`socket()` returns a file descriptor if this is what you are referring to as a socket ID then the ways to get this without the process's collaboration on windows are limited. FWIW on linux open FDs are enumerated in the proc filesystem.

That being said, the only thing you would be able to do with the fd is send additional information from the socket. You could also read from the fd, but any data read in this way would *not* be sent to the application that owns the socket. Without some coordination, that would probably not be what you desire as you would just get bits and pieces of data.

If just want to be able to listen in on the traffic in your program, then something like packet filtering should be sufficient so I assume you actually want to be able to be like a man in the middle for it.

If this is the case, then the best thing to do would actually be to set your application up as a proxy for your other service.

By this I mean, write a program that opens a listening port and accepts connections when a connection is initiated, it should immediately open its own connection to a pre-configured IP:port combination and begin forwarding traffic. Once this is written it's a simple matter to inspect the traffic before forwarding and possibly modify it.

If your program is a server, run it on a non-standard port, configure this application to open the server's normal port and then forward connections to the non-standard port you set up on localhost.

If your program is a client, simply point the interceptor application at the server and choose a random listen port on your box. Then configure the client to connect to this listen port as though it were the server.

This should work for pretty much anything. The only caveat is if the traffic is encrypted you will (obviously) not be able to inspect/modify it. This is effectively the same as placing your application behind a NAT.